# Is this a bug in the Log class in CodenameOne?

Tags: codenameone

I've been trying to use the log class to capture some strange device-specific failures using local storage.  When I went into the Log class and traced the code I noticed what seems to be a bug.

when I call the p(String) method, it calls getWriter() to get the 'output' instance of the Writer.  It will notice output is null so it calls createWriter() create it.   Since I haven't set a File URL, the following code gets executed:

```
if(getFileURL() == null) {
    return new OutputStreamWriter(Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream("CN1Log__$"));
}
```

On the Simulator, I notice this file is created and contains log info.

so in my app I want to display the logs after an error is detected (to debug).  I call getLogContent() to retrieve it as a string but it does some strange things:

```
if(instance.isFileWriteEnabled()) {
    if(instance.getFileURL() == null) {
        instance.setFileURL("file:///" + FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getRoots()[0] + "/codenameOne.log");
    }
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(instance.getFileURL()));
```

The main problem I see is that it's using a different file URL than the default writer location.   and since the creation of the Writer didn't set the File URL, the getLogContent method will never see the logged data.   (The other issue I have is a style issue that a method getting content shouldn't be setting the location for that content persistently for the instance, but that's another story).

As a workaround I think I can just call "getLogContent()" at the beginning of the application which should set the file url correctly in a place that it will retrieve it from later.  I'll test that next.

In the mean time, is this a Bug, or is it functionality I don't understand from my user perspective?

Answer (score 0):

It's more like "unimplemented functionality". This specific API dates back to LWUIT.

The main problem with that method is that we are currently writing into a log file and getting its contents which we might currently be in the middle of writing into can be a problem and might actually cause a failure. So this approach was mostly abandoned in favor of the more robust crash protection approach.